# Почему конфиг nuxt js отображает стили на сайте

Tags: nuxt.js

Подключаю стили в конфиге, они применяются и при этом отображаются на сайте.

```typescript
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: [
        '@/assets/css/styles.css',]
})
```

[image: Пример отображения]

Comment: Ищи что-то типа `style { display: block }` или `* { display: block }`.